# Convert this string "mÃ%83Âºsica" into "música" without replace method

Tags: c#

Recently downloaded some files from my server and i'm now facing this trouble with some characters, make a c# app where put all my files into a string and then use the replace method but there is a lot of work, i wanna know if there's a most general way to get this text back to normal
I tried this:

```
String a="pequeÃ±o";
a=a.replace("Ã±","ñ");
```

but i think that this is a good solve for my problem, there is a general way to do this

Comment: What encoding are you using to read the files?

Comment: And what is the original file encoding?

Comment: *How* are you loading the files as strings at all?

Comment: It seems that you already used the wrong encoding and got a wrong string. Too late to restore it including all cases.

Comment: Is it bad to read files as strings?

Comment: utf8, the files are on my computer, i make a code that pass all the names into a textbox, i have a button that change the names of the files, but there are too many names for example "fotografÃ%83Â­a" into "fotografía"

Comment: Looks like there is a problem when i use some spanish speacial characters like "ñ" "á" "ú" ...

Comment: The problem occurred earlier, solve it at the source.

Comment: Henk you give me a solution, but i can see it now? Did you delete it?

Comment: i can't*  see it now... Can you show me your answer again?

Comment: Yes deleted, it didn't really work. Not for  "mÃ%83Âºsica" anyway, I don't even recognize that encoding.

Comment: try with "mÂºsica" the "Ã%83" can be changed by ""

Comment: Well, `"mÃºsica"` works, `"mÂºsica"` does not. I will undelete but it's only a partial solution.

Comment: well this looks to be the only general solution i will mark it as answer

Comment: Do read the comments again. You are repairing damage that might be preventable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up the encoding during download. Like pushing UTF-8 bytes through an ASCCI Encoding or something like that.  In order to solve it, we need to see the code that does the downloading.

A systematic way to repair this w/o Replace:

```
string a ="pequeÃ±o";
byte[] b1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(a);
byte[] b2 = b1.Where(b => b != 0).ToArray(); // get rid of the '\0' bytes
string t = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b2);      // "pequeño"
```

And provided you can convert `"mÃ%83Âºsica"` to `"mÃºsica"` in some way it will work for that too. I don't really see the pattern here.

Comment: That *systematic* way is just a hope. It wouldn't work for `string s1 = "Ç";
            var buf1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254").GetBytes(s1);
            string a = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf1);`. (just an example encoding) As you said in your comment. It is too late for a remedy.